# Converting an MLMultiArray (output shape) to SCNGeometry

Tags: scenekit, arkit, coreml

has anyone had luck efficiently converting an MLMultiArray to custom geometry? I've been able to convert MLMultiArray -> UIImage, though unsure how to efficiently create a custom geometry.

Big picture - I'm trying to mask a Scenekit Scene by utilizing an SCNNode with custom geometry. Essentially, I'd like to create a portal effect as seen in many of the online demos/tutorials. Though, rather than using an SCNBox as the geometry for the masking node, I'd like to use output data from my CoreML model as the "masking" shape.

If anyone can share code samples or high-level approaches, I'd greatly appreciate it! Thank you

*Example app using custom geometry for portal mask*
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dark-subject-one/id1312987602

[Image of custom geometry mask used in portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhyBw.jpg)

Comment: What is inside your MLMultiArray?

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans - it's the output of my CoreML Model: MultiArray (Double 1 x 224 x 224) defined as let multiArray: MLMultiArray = observations[0].featureValue.multiArrayValue. I then convert this mask data to a UIImage, eg. let semiTransparentMask = maskToRGBA(maskArray: MultiArray<Double>(multiArray), rgba: (0, 255, 0, 100.0))!

Comment: Right, so it's a segmentation mask of some sort? And you want to turn this into a mesh that you can attach to an SCNNode. So you'll need some kind of routine that can turn a bitmap into (one or more) polygons.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the direction @MatthijsHollemans!